# FontAwesome icon is not showing

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I am using Font Awesome icons several places on my page, but when I want to use it in CSS it is not showing. I went through a lot of question here because I see other people had the same problem, but none of the solutions worked for me:

My Font Awesome version is: Font Awesome Free 5.11.2

**CSS:**

```
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input+label::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: '\f574';
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #757575;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try `"Font Awesome 5 Pro";` and let me know if it works

Comment: @TemaniAfif Mine is working fine with `'Font Awesome 5 Free'`. I'm still looking around to see what could be causing the problem for AME.

Comment: It must be with the installation/loading of Font Awesome because the CSS you provided works fine in my environment.

Comment: @eyl327 you are probably using the CDN and he's using the kit that's why I need to verify because I have a Duplicate for each case

Comment: "Font Awesome 5 Pro" doesn't work neither.

Comment: @eyl327 So could you help me how to set up Font Awesome in my project?

Comment: @AME I included this css file for fontawesome: https://pastebin.com/2DQrMmhR using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">` and I believe that is all I needed.

Comment: Oh ... I also had this CSS, but the only I included was the fontawesome.css not the all.css. Now it works for me. If you make an answer of it, I going to accept it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AME Thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use FontAwesome symbols in CSS, I needed to include [all.css](https://pastebin.com/2DQrMmhR) from FontAwesome.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
```

(The `all.css` file is saved in a folder called `css` that I created.)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the CSS folder and Fonts folder are in the same parent directory

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH3Sg.jpg)

Comment: They are in the same folder.